# Repetitive reports

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have a report that uses the same number a lot of times throught the text (money reference $). 
There`s a way to automate this refference so I update only the "main field"?

Thanks

Example:
pg. 1 = The total amount is $ 5.430,10... 
pg. 20 = In the report $ 5.430,10...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `\newcommand*{\mymoney}{5,430,10}` in the preamble and then just `\mymoney{}` in the text?

Comment: Also, use `\$`.

Answer (score 4):

If one and the same text string, e.g., `$ 5.430,10`, occurs over and over again, I'd create a macro for it. E.g., you could place the following instruction in the preamble

```
\newcommand\myamount{\$5.430,10}  % note the backslash character before "$"
```

and then write something like the following in the body of the text:

```
The total amount is \myamount\dots In the report \myamount\dots
```